# Fail to execute google UpgradableAPI with oauth1

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-oauth, marketplace

Our issue is solved, scroll down to see our original issue.

**So here is the complete working code, I wrapped it in a method**
(System.in is used to input access token, so you don't have to sign in again and again in browser like me) :

```
public static void executeUpgradableApi() throws IOException {
    OAuthHmacSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSigner();
    signer.clientSharedSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET;

    System.out.println("Please input the access token in the console and press Enter. If you don't have access token, press Enter directly.");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String accessToken = br.readLine();

    if (accessToken == null || accessToken.trim().length() == 0) {
        // Get Temporary Token
        String scopes = URLEncoder.encode("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "UTF-8");
        OAuthGetTemporaryToken getTemporaryToken = new OAuthGetTemporaryToken("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=" + scopes);
        getTemporaryToken.signer = signer;
        getTemporaryToken.consumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
        getTemporaryToken.transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        getTemporaryToken.callback = "http://localhost:8888/";
        OAuthCredentialsResponse temporaryTokenResponse = getTemporaryToken.execute();

        // Build Authenticate URL
        OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl accessTempToken = new OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
        accessTempToken.temporaryToken = temporaryTokenResponse.token;
        String authUrl = accessTempToken.build();

        // Redirect to Authenticate URL in order to get Verifier Code
        System.out.println("Please open this url in browser and authorize the request: " + authUrl);

        String verifierCode = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Continue with verifier code [" + verifierCode + "], request token=[" + temporaryTokenResponse.token + "]");

        // Get Access Token using Temporary token and Verifier Code
        OAuthGetAccessToken getAccessToken = new OAuthGetAccessToken("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
        signer.tokenSharedSecret = temporaryTokenResponse.tokenSecret;
        getAccessToken.signer = signer;
        getAccessToken.temporaryToken=temporaryTokenResponse.token;
        getAccessToken.transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        getAccessToken.verifier= verifierCode;
        getAccessToken.consumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
        OAuthCredentialsResponse accessTokenResponse = getAccessToken.execute();

        accessToken = accessTokenResponse.token;
    }
    System.out.println("accessToken:[" + accessToken + "]");
    // Build OAuthParameters in order to use them while accessing the resource
    OAuthParameters oauthParameters = new OAuthParameters();
    oauthParameters.signer = signer;
    oauthParameters.consumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
    oauthParameters.token = accessToken;
    oauthParameters.version = "1.0";

    // Use OAuthParameters to access the desired Resource URL
    HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory(oauthParameters);
    // GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp");
    GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl(API_ENDPOINT);
    HttpContent content = new EmptyContent();
    HttpResponse response = requestFactory.buildPutRequest(genericUrl, content).setLoggingEnabled(true).execute();
    System.out.println(response.parseAsString());
}
```

========================**Here is the old question:**========================

We have an oauth1 app in google marketplace and we want to upgrade it to oauth2 recently with google UpgradableAPI. However I always get signature_invalid error when get access token. I'm stuck here now. Also the oauth1 playground seems to be removed so I cannot debug.

To execute UpgradableAPI with oauth1, I found some example code from stackoverflow, and changed a bit. I posted it below, please help to check if there is anything wrong or missing in the code. Many thanks.

```
    OAuthHmacSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSigner();
    // Get request Token
    OAuthGetTemporaryToken getTemporaryToken = new OAuthGetTemporaryToken("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
    signer.clientSharedSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET;
    getTemporaryToken.signer = signer;
    getTemporaryToken.consumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
    getTemporaryToken.transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    getTemporaryToken.callback = "http://aaa.aaa.com/aaa"; // A fake url here, just to get verifier code
    OAuthCredentialsResponse temporaryTokenResponse = getTemporaryToken.execute();

    // Build Authenticate URL
    OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl accessTempToken = new OAuthAuthorizeTemporaryTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
    accessTempToken.temporaryToken = temporaryTokenResponse.token;
    String authUrl = accessTempToken.build();

    // Redirect to Authenticate URL in order to get Verifier Code
    System.out.println(authUrl);

    // Open the link in browser and get verifier code from the callback url.

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String verifierCode = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("Continue with verifier code [" + verifierCode + "]");

    // Get Access Token using Temporary token and Verifier Code
    OAuthGetAccessToken getAccessToken = new OAuthGetAccessToken("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    getAccessToken.signer = signer;
    getAccessToken.temporaryToken=temporaryTokenResponse.token;
    getAccessToken.transport = new NetHttpTransport();
    getAccessToken.verifier= verifierCode;
    getAccessToken.consumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
    **OAuthCredentialsResponse accessTokenResponse = getAccessToken.execute(); // Always get signature_invalid error here!!!!!!!!!**

    // Build OAuthParameters in order to use them while accessing the resource
    OAuthParameters oauthParameters = new OAuthParameters();
    signer.tokenSharedSecret = accessTokenResponse.tokenSecret;
    oauthParameters.signer = signer;
    oauthParameters.consumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
    oauthParameters.token = accessTokenResponse.token;
    oauthParameters.verifier = verifierCode;

    // Use OAuthParameters to access the desired Resource URL
    HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new NetHttpTransport().createRequestFactory(oauthParameters);
    GenericUrl genericUrl = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/ListingID/ChromeWebstoreItemId/domain");
    HttpResponse response = requestFactory.buildPutRequest(genericUrl, null).execute();
    System.out.println(response.parseAsString());
```

The error from google is:

> com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
>   signature_invalid
>   base_string:GET&https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2FOAuthGetAccessToken&oauth_consumer_key%3Dxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com%26oauth_nonce%3D27f03753d137a12b%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1408872174%26oauth_token%3D4%25XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%26oauth_verifier%3DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I have found the problem, when get access token, I forgot to add token secret to signer from "get request token" response. After add the token secret, I can get access token successfully. I hope this question and answer would help someone like me what struggling with oauth v1.

I'm now stuck on the last step which is to execute the upgradable API. It always return 401 unauthorized error. Will keep working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The upgradable API successfully executed. The issue that it always return 401 unauthorized is, there is no need to add token secret in signer and no need to add verifier in oauth params.